# How to input SQL query from command line, and retrieve output in simpler format

Tags: sql, firebird, nsis

I'm using Firebird's `isql.exe` tool to query an existing database:

```
isql -u <username> -p <password> <database> -i <file.sql> -o <output.txt>
```

This reads my SQL statements from `file.sql` and saves the results to `output.txt`.

Is there a way to feed the SQL statements into `isql` via command line, and not from a file?

This is because I actually plan to execute the command above in my .exe installer script (via `ExecWait` of NSIS Installer).

Also, is there a way to format the output such that only the actual info needed are returned? Currently the output's first line contains the column names, second line a bunch of "====" as separator, third line the actual info, with an arbitrary number of spaces in between each column. This output format makes it hard for me to use in my script.

Comment: Regarding your second question: [SET HEADING](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/isql-set.html#isql-set-heading)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For your first problem, you can use Firebird isql without an input file as:

```
echo select * from rdb$database; | isql -u sysdba -p password C:\path\to\db.fdb
```

This redirects the standard output from echo (value `select * from rdb$database;`) to the standard input of isql. The result of the query (or queries) will be printed to the standard output of isql (or to file if you use `-o`).

However as echo is a feature of the command prompt, I am not certain if this will work from NSIS. Otherwise you will need something that does the same thing as echo: print its parameter values to the standard out.

As I commented before, for your second question you should look at [`SET HEADING`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-set-heading) and maybe [`SET WIDTH`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/isql/firebird-isql.html#isql-set-width).

Comment: Perfect! I got it to work without the `$database` part. Thank you very much

Comment: I'm using `SET LIST ON`, but it seems `SET HEADING OFF` doesn't affect it. Is there a way to hide the column names when setting `LIST` to `ON`?

Comment: @Obay Not as far as I know.

Comment: @Obay There is no `$database` part in my answer: `rdb$datbase` is a (system) table I used for the example

Answer (score 1):

I case others find this useful, I was actually able to implement this in NSIS by using `$PLUGINSDIR`, which is a temporary folder created by NSIS at runtime. I created a temporary input and output file in that folder. I wrote the SQL statements into the input file using `FileWrite` and read the output using `FileRead`